# nav logo proper link href

Tags: html, css, web

I am learning how to create header and I have problem with proper link href. My logo-box wraps image(logo) and name of the company but in order to align them with display flex it covers full width. I want that href only works when I hover logo or name not whole box. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo-block">
                    <a href="" class="logo-block-link">
                        <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
                        <h3 class="logo-tittle">Company</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav{
    background-color: salmon;
}

.container{
    padding: 15px 0;
    background-color: #fdcb9e;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-block{
    flex:1;
    border:1px solid gold;
}

.logo-block-link{
    display: flex;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.logo{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.nav-list{
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-tittle{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#3f3f44;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-list li a{
    font-size:16px;
    color:#3f3f44;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you should break the `<a href="#" class="logo-block-link"><img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>` and `<a href="#"><h3 class="logo-tittle">Company</h3></a>` into 2 `div`. Then, use `float: left` to make the 2 div in one row. After that, place the `flex: 1` to parent of the 2 div. You will be able to use href working when you click on the logo or the name.

For more detail, see below sample code:

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <style>
  *{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 nav{
  background-color: salmon;
 }

 .container{
  padding: 15px 0;
  background-color: #fdcb9e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .logo-block{
  border:1px solid gold;
 }

 .logo-block-link{
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid black;
 }

 .logo{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 }

 .nav-list{
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .logo-tittle{
  font-size:20px;
  color:#3f3f44;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 .nav-list li a{
  font-size:16px;
  color:#3f3f44;
  font-family: monospace;
 }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div style="flex: 1;">
                    <div class="logo-block" style="float: left;">
                        <a href="#" class="logo-block-link">
                            <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7d821e531f911facf0f644c1e708dd99?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="" class="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <a href="#">
                          <h3 class="logo-tittle">Company</h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> " I want that href only works when I hover logo or name not whole box "
>   I recomend you do it in JS, for example you can activate link by adding attribute href with value. So for example:

```
 <a>This is link </a>
```

You add attribute href='yourlink' by js and you get `<a href='yourlink'>This is link </a>` and it should works.

So in javaScript:

```
Aelement.setAttribute('href','yourlink');
```